# Using modernizr to detect iOS devices

Tags: javascript, ios, modernizr

So i'm trying to download a image, I use `window.location = data.url;` which points to the file the image however, in iOS it sends it to the actual image where you need to tap and hold to save.

I know there's no way around this however, I feel it breaks the journey so wanted to just direct them to another page I create with the image and text saying "tap and hold" so the user knows.

I had a look at the documentation but got lost. How can I detect if someone is using an iOS device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modernizr is all about `feature detection`, not device/browser detection via UA string sniffing.

Device/browser detection is a bad guy for some time and it's unlikely for this to change - it's been proved that it is unreliable for multiple reasons.

However, if you are determined to go this way, I can suggest you to check out [isMobile](https://github.com/kaimallea/isMobile/) - a simple javascript lib for mobile device detection.